# Find point closest to the given point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the closest point of the graph $y=\sqrt x$ to the point $(4,0)$.

This is how I understand it:

[image]

I assume that triangle with the sides $a$, $x$ and $x/2$ and the largest triangle are similar triangles. From that I conclude that the smaller triangle's one side is $x/2$.

The closest point on the graph from $(4,0)$ must be in the intersection of the lines $a$, $b$ and $c$. $$a = \sqrt{x^2+(x/2)^2},\quad b = \sqrt{x^2 + (2-x/2)^2},\quad c = \sqrt{(4-x)^2+(x/2)^2}$$ by the Pythagorean theorem.

I have to minimize the sum $a+b+c$ by diferentiating and then solving for $x$, and then subtracting $x$ from 4 would get the abscissa of the wanted point.

Solving with [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Diferentiate%20sqrt%28x%5E2%2b%28x/2%29%5E2%29%2bsqrt%28x%5E2%20%2b%20%282-x/2%29%5E2%29%2bsqrt%28%284-x%29%5E2%2b%28x/2%29%5E2%29%29,%20solve%20for%20x) $x \approx 0.57$, so the abscissa is $4-0.57=3.43$, ordinate is $0.57/2=0.285$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Is the point you obtained on the graph of $y=\sqrt x$?  It does not look so. I do not see the rational for $a,b,c$. Pick $x,\sqrt x$ and minimize distance..

Comment: You're supposed to find the point $(x,\sqrt x)$ which minimizes the distance to $(4,0)$. You know how to find the distance between those two points using the Pythagorean theorem, right? I have no idea how you came up with all the triangles in your question.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking that distance of a point from a curve is the sum of distances of  some central point from certain "corners" of a shape. The problem is just asking about the point ON parabola that is closest to $(4,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance from a point on the graph $y=\sqrt{x}$ to the point $(4,0)$ is $$\sqrt{(x-4)^2+(\sqrt{x}-0)^2}.$$ This will be minimized precisely when $$(x-4)^2+(\sqrt{x}-0)^2=x^2-8x+16+x=x^2-7x+16$$ is minimized, since $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is an increasing function. Do you know how to find $x\geq 0$ that minimizes $x^2-7x+16$?

Comment: So when minimized, the point would be $(3.5, \sqrt(3.5))$?

Comment: @Cobold: Exactly.

Comment: Great, Thanks!!